# Run a script if not already running - getting [0: not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run a script if not already running using another script.

```
test $ ls
arcane_script.py  calling_script.sh
```

This is what my script looks right now

```
test $ cat calling_script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

PROCESSES_RUNNING=$(ps -ef | grep "arcane_script.py" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l)
echo $PROCESSES_RUNNING
if [$PROCESSES_RUNNING = "0"]; then
    /usr/bin/python arcane_script.py
fi;
```

I've tried other variants within the `if` block, like `[$PROCESSES_RUNNING -eq 0]`, but all of them output the same error message

```
test $ ./calling_script.sh 
0
./calling_script.sh: line 5: [0: command not found
test $ sh calling_script.sh 
0
calling_script.sh: 5: calling_script.sh: [0: not found
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it? I've googled around, but couldnt find much help.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but all examples of ifs I've seen have spaces after the braces for example: if [ condition ] instead of: if [condition]

Comment: @BenjyKessler Spot on, that worked. Post it as an answer with the explanation and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash you need to protect the brackets with spaces. Brackets are just a shorthand for the `test` command. And in bash commands must be separated by spaces. See [this link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) for more detail. So you need to write `if [ condition ]` instead of `if [condition]`.

Answer (score 3):

You need a space around the brackets:

```
[ $PROCESSES_RUNNING = "0" ]
```

The reason why is that `[` is actually the name of command and in shell all commands must be separated from other words by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A more solid way would be to use a pid file. Then, if the pid file exist you know it is a running process. 
The idea is to write the processID to a file (for example in /tmp) at the start of the program, and remove it when it ends. Another program can simply check if the pid file exist.

At the start of your python file add something like

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

pid = str(os.getpid())
pidfile = "/tmp/arcane_script.pid"

if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
    print "%s already exists, exiting" % pidfile
    sys.exit()
else:
    file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)

# Do some actual work here


#
os.unlink(pidfile)
```

This way you don't even need the extra bash start script. 
If you want to check using bash anyway, simply look for the pid:

```
cat /tmp/arcane_script.pid 2>/dev/null && echo "" || echo "Not running"
```

Note that the pid file needs to be removed manually if your script didn't end correctly.

ps. Have a look at Monit if you want to automatically check if the PID exists. It can restart the program if needed.

Comment: Can you explain me more about this? Also, what is the `$!` syntax?

Comment: `$!` returns the processID of the started script. However, since you use  python I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was not looking to do it via a file, because if a process falls to remove the file due to any reason, then the next tasks wouldn't run. Anyway, +1 for the answer.

Comment: ok. ps, you might want to read the first Q/A here https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ

Comment: Thanks for the link, really insightful.